# Put Login in Popup window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, authentication

I'm creating a login where you click on a button and it shows the login via  `$("#loginbox").show();`, I want to show the contents in loginbox/`<div class="loginContainer">` in a popup window. I've been trying to use `window.open()` but I don't think it'll work for what I want.

my code:

```
    const $document = $(document);
        const $login = $("#login");
        const $loginBox = $("#loginbox");

        const $formElement = $(`
          <div class="loginContainer">
            <label for="userNameBox"><b>Username: </b></label>
            <input type="text" class="userName"id="userNameBox" placeholder="Enter Username"required="required">
            <input type="button" class="loginButton" id="loginButton" value="Login"/>
          </div>
        `);
$document.on("click", "#loginButton", function() {
          const $userNameBox = $("#userNameBox");

          if ($userNameBox.val() !== "") {
            location.href = "mylink.com";
          } else {
            alert("Please Enter a Username.");
            location.reload();
          }
        });

          $('.login').click(function(e) {

          if ($loginBox.children().length === 0) {
            $loginBox.append($formElement);

          }

          $("#loginbox").show();

          event.preventDefault();
          return false;
        });
```